# Is this a C variable?

Tags: c

I was asked to explain what this C variable is: `int *x();`. To me, this doesn't look like a variable, but a function prototype. Am I right?

EDIT: Someone posted an answer mentioning [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) as a tool to verify one's assumptions when in doubt, but now that answer has been deleted, so I'll mention it again.

Comment: It is not a prototype: it's a declaration. A prototype specifies both the return type and the types of the parameters (or `void` if the function has no parameters). Also, in case of doubt, you can name `x` an "identifier" :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, that would be a declaration of a function returning a pointer-to-int and takes an unspecified number of arguments. The declaration of a function that takes no arguments would be `int *x(void);`

Comment: +1 correct answer at last! but ... it takes an unspecified (but fixed and determined by the function implementation) number of arguments.

Comment: @pmg: Good point! It has been some time since I have programmed in C so my memory is obviously not serving me so well any more, haha!

Comment: The declarations for a function taking any number of arguments would be `int *x(...)`, which is invalid because at least one argument is mandatory, you can, however, write a function that takes 1 or more arguments :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a function declaration. pmg explained the difference between a function declaration and a function prototype in his comment.

The function returns a pointer to a variable which has int as data type.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, that's a function that returns a pointer to an `int`. It would be a bit easier to get if it were written as `int* x();`.

Comment: It is not a function. It doesn't return anything. It is a declaration.